# Is it possible to do Single Port Forwarding by machine name?

Tags: windows, networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I setup my router (DynDNS + open port and redirect to specific IP with Single Port Forwarding) and desktop PC to allow me to remote desktop to my desktop PC. This work very well, but if my desktop PC happens to change IP address (IP address attributed by my router -- 192.168.0.***), I have to go back to the router settings and update my configuration. My router is a Linksys WRT610N.

I was wondering if there is another option apart from assigning a static IP address? Is it possible to route using machine?

Comment: in your router's DHCP settings, there should be a "reserve ip" option, where you can reserve an IP for use with a MAC address (or hardware address).

Comment: Wow! I never noticed that option. This is exactly what I need. Thank you Waleed!